# Monaco-editor need to underline whole text for go-to definition

Tags: monaco-editor

I have monaco-editor and definitionProvider set.
See example picture [image: example]

I hold ctrl and hover over the value.
I am trying to underline the whole object (when it has spaces), but it highlights only one word instead of the whole value.

Code for test
https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html

```
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: "function hello() {\n\talert('Hello world!');\n}",
    language: 'javascript'
});

monaco.languages.registerDefinitionProvider('javascript', {
    provideDefinition: (model) => {

      return {
        uri: model.uri,
        range: {
          startColumn: 1,
          startLineNumber: 1,
          endColumn: 1,
          endLineNumber: 1,
        },
      }
    },
  })
```

What part did I miss? How to make an underline for the whole `Hello world`?

I know that this is possible, because it has in vscode

I have tried to find some properties inside monaco-editor options but seems like I missed some good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found `wordPattern` in monaco-editor language configuration and updated it with my case + system.